# Test app on iPhone via Xcode on development server

Tags: ios, node.js, iphone, xcode

***Problem***

I'm developing a full stack application and when I try testing on my physical iPhone via Xcode, the iOS app doesn't seem to be connecting to either my development server of my client server.

I'm using React Native for the iOS app and Node as my server

Does anyone know why this might be occurring and how to solve the problem?

***Error from React Native Console Log***

```
login error Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:580)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:394)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:507
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:190)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:366)
    at MessageQueue.js:106
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:314)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

***Answer***

You need to change your server url from  'http://localhost:port' to  'http://computerIPAddress/port'.  If you're using .env I suggest changing it where you're actually making the server call because changing the development .env doesn't seem to take effect.

This may not be the best solution, ideally there would be another .env file for this so you don't need to change any code anytime you want to test on a physical phone but at least it works!

If anyone has a cleaner solution I'd love to hear it!